# Filter in sale.order list

Tags: python, openerp-8

In odoo, I need to list all the orders are paid, but not entirely (so all orders with a first facture). 
I extended sale_order class with this code, but it does not works (I have no error message)

```
class sale(osv.osv):
def _invoiced_search(self, cursor, user, obj, name, args, context=None):
    if not len(args):
        return []
    clause = ''
    sale_clause = ''
    no_invoiced = False
    for arg in args:
        if (arg[1] == '=' and arg[2]) or (arg[1] == '!=' and not arg[2]):
            clause += 'AND inv.state = \'open\' AND inv.residual != \'0.0\' AND inv.residual != inv.amount_total '
        else:
            clause += 'AND inv.state != \'cancel\' AND sale.state != \'cancel\' AND inv.state = \'paid\' AND rel.order_id = sale.id '
            clause += 'AND inv.state = \'open\' AND inv.residual != \'0.0\' AND inv.residual != inv.amount_total '
            sale_clause = ',  sale_order AS sale '

            clause += 'AND inv.state = \'open\' AND inv.residual = inv.amount_total'
            no_invoiced = True

    cursor.execute('SELECT rel.order_id ' \
            'FROM sale_order_invoice_rel AS rel, account_invoice AS inv '+ sale_clause + \
            'WHERE rel.invoice_id = inv.id ' + clause)
    res = cursor.fetchall()
    if no_invoiced:
        cursor.execute('SELECT sale.id ' \
                'FROM sale_order AS sale ' \
                'WHERE sale.id NOT IN ' \
                    '(SELECT rel.order_id ' \
                    'FROM sale_order_invoice_rel AS rel) ' \
                'AND sale.state != \'cancel\'')
        res.extend(cursor.fetchall())
    if not res:
        return [('id', '=', 0)]
    return [('id', 'in', [x[0] for x in res])]

def _partial_invoiced(self, cursor, user, ids, name, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    for sale in self.browse(cursor, user, ids, context=context):
        res[sale.id] = False
        invoice_existence = False
        for invoice in sale.invoice_ids:
            if invoice.state!='cancel':
                invoice_existence = True
                if invoice.state == 'open' and invoice.residual != '0.0':
                    res[sale.id] = True
                    break
        if not invoice_existence or sale.state == 'manual':
            res[sale.id] = False
        return res

_inherit = 'sale.order'     
_columns = {
        'partially_invoiced': fields.function(_partial_invoiced, string='Paid',
        fnct_search=_invoiced_search, type='boolean', help="It indicates that an invoice is partially paid."),
                }
```

Help ;)

Comment: `but its not works` you have to be more specific

Comment: Please don't put nonsense like `oooooooooooooooooooooooooooo` or `asasdfsdfaregfaerg` in your question

Comment: "but its not works you have to be more specific"
Filter don't work.
 
i'm bad in english sorry (i've very difficult to explain most)